# С++, из списка слов длины 3 или 4, найти слова которые являются палиндромом

Tags: c++, хеширование

**Стоит задача**:
Разработать функции **хеширования** со свойствами *h(a,b,c)= h(c,b,a) и h(a,b,c,d)= h(d,c,b,a).* Для списка слов из трех или четырех букв, подсчитать количество **палиндромов** для каждого слова. Метод разрешения коллизий – линейный.

Преподаватель объяснил, что список слов - файл с словами, которые могут быть даже бессмысленными, но длины 3 или 4. Среди них есть палиндромы.
И дальше по вопросу.
Не понятны 2 вещи:

1. Как лучше реализовать хэш-функцию, для палиндромов она должна давать одинаковые хэши независимо от того, реверсированная строка была подана или нет. Преподаватель привел в пример сумму аски-кодов, но такая хэш-функция совсем не устойчива к коллизиям...
2. Как сделать поиск количества палиндромов из букв палиндрома (которые так же могут быть бессмысленными, но палиндромами.

Answer (score 0):

Реализовал искомую функцию хеширования `PaliHash(str)`, чтобы она обладала нужными свойствами (хеш обратного порядка совпадает с хешем прямого) мы просто из двух строк прямой и обратной выбираем ту которая [лексикографически](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA) меньше и хешируем её обычным хешем, благодаря выбору меньшей из строк мы автоматически реализуем это свойстово что прямой и обратный порядок даёт одинаковый хеш (подумайте почему).

В качестве обычного хеша для строки я использую [std::hash](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash), у него обычно (в популярных компиляторах) очень мало коллизий.

Далее, для второй задачи (подсчёта числа палиндромов для входных символов) я использовал [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation), эта функция позволяет перебрать все возможные перестановки букв, чтобы сгенерировать все возможные слова, сгенерировав все слова я считаю сколько из них обладают свойство палиндромности. Вывод программы в консоль указывает для каждого набора букв количество палиндромов, которое можно из них построить.

Саму проверку [палиндромности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC) я реализовал просто - реверсирую строку (используя `RevStr(str)` функцию, основанную на [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)) и если она совпала с исходной, то значит это палиндром, если нет, то не палиндром.

Для простоты я входные слова ни читал из файла, а задал список (вектор) в виде константы `words`.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##dVLLboMwELzzFSsqtaCkUc8E0muPVfsBkWM2YMmxkW2SqhHfTv0IwUSqL2ZnZ3dnx9Cue6WciGYcn5igvK8RSm0UE80umZFjL6hhUhAeo0xaJpJTjBHeSMVMuwDPSI1UuyRhgjOBoE1dFGEKfOH526gshnQO1wTs8aDCMyqNmd4csGEiy9egNyjqLM@3nqXQ9EqA3ibDPIH94t7AJ@Hsg@h20Z5KoQ08P4xpLa2MaDtwCKrtTLnVKw3VXfaDBigrl3@/Fds8FNO3cmQv0cCJuE3i@cGjpYKLVLUbdk0JIekaUnKg4Zqi@hYe0iEIOUoFGemN9MVFaDENmjeRymQuNXvqo9hWTw42dtbGPbWyK3ibk7WM2rrDjuCbQnX3x4V5vmC5s1pNLed2A1xaxhHCWwn8MfsO1ak3xP15/6uN5bpKKnsDZQnpS@ouL8iHBXjgvowDrXuhfLAvM45/)

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

inline std::string RevStr(std::string s) {
    std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    return s;
}

inline size_t PaliHash(std::string const & s) {
    std::hash<std::string> hasher;
    std::string rs = RevStr(s);
    return s <= rs ? hasher(s) : hasher(rs);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> words = {"aaa", "abc", "aba", "abcd", "abab"};
    for (auto word: words) {
        std::sort(word.begin(), word.end());
        size_t pali_cnt = 0;
        do {
            if (word == RevStr(word))
                ++pali_cnt;
        } while (std::next_permutation(word.begin(), word.end()));
        std::cout << "'" << word << "': " << pali_cnt << ", ";
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
'aaa': 1, 'abc': 0, 'aab': 1, 'abcd': 0, 'aabb': 2,
```